# How to open new cmd tab by Win+X with current directory from Far as working directory

Tags: conemu, far-manager

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortkey opens a new console cmd tab with far3 home directory as starting point.

I wish <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open cmd the same way, but the working dir to stay the same as the current one in far3 manager.

Example:

1. open far in conemu
2. go to any directory d:/any/dir
3. press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
4. new console tab with cmd open
5. working directory should be `d:/any/dir`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> runs new tab instance regardless of current tab state. That is by default.

You may type `cmd -new_console` in Far prompt and press Enter.
That will do the trick.

For your comfort you may create macro in Far Manager or key macro in ConEmu.

**Far Manager**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and type

```
[Esc] cmd -new_console [Enter]
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and choose desired hotkey.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to save changes.

**ConEmu**

Goto settings, keys & macro and create new macro

```
print("\ecmd -new_console\n")
```

Choose desired hotkey and save settings